# cmd insert text into the middle of the file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am moving files from one directory to a newly created directory. Currently the script inserts the id variable to the start of the file name for all the file names.
I would like to insert the id variable after model name variable in all the file names. How do I do that?

I have the following code in my cmd file.

```
@echo off

rem set 12d variables
set modelname=dr network_
set id=10yr_

mkdir "%modelname%"

rem move to new dir created
move "%modelname%*.rpt" "%modelname%"

rem change working directory
cd "%modelname%"

rem for each file rename it and add the new prefix %id% to the file name 
for %%f in ("%modelname%*.rpt") do (

    rename "%%f" "%id%%%f"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few small alterations, should get you going.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem set 12d variables
set modelname=dr network_
set id=10yr_

mkdir "%modelname%"

rem move to new dir created
move "%modelname%*.rpt" "%modelname%"

rem change working directory
cd "%modelname%"

rem Work out how long the modelname is
echo %modelname%>strlen.txt
for %%a in (strlen.txt) do set /a modelNameLength=%%~za - 2
del strlen.txt

rem for each file rename it and add the new text %id% to the middle of the file name 
for %%f in ("%modelname%*.rpt") do (
    set newfilename=%%f
    set newfilename=!newfilename:~0,%modelNameLength%!%id%!newfilename:~%modelNameLength%!
    ren "%%f" "!newfilename!"
)
```

Comment: Hi Scott thank you for your post. If the folder and files already exist in the specific location I get the error "A subdirectory or file ... already exists. This does not occur if these files are being copying for the first time. How do I get around this. Also how would this be done in powershell.

Comment: Change the ren line to: `if not exist "!newfilename! ren "%%f" "!newfilename!"`  Sorry, can't help you with a powershell solution - I really should look into it, but it's never installed on the servers I have to play with.

Answer (score 0):

tfizhardinge, 
  Scott C provided the correct answer using cmd.

Here is a Powershell option for you, I've tried to match your cmd code, so you can see what is going on.

```
# Rename using replace to insert text in the middle of the name

# Set directory where the files you want to rename reside
# This will allow you to run the script from outside the source directory
Set-Variable -Name sourcedir -Value "c:\test"

# Set folder and rename variables
Set-Variable -Name modelname -Value "dr network_"
Set-Variable -Name id        -Value "10yr_"

# Set new filename which is modelname string + id variable
Set-Variable -Name newmodelname -Value $modelname$id

# Check if folder exisits, if not create
if(!(Test-Path -Path $sourcedir\$modelname )){
    # rem make directoy with modelname variable
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $sourcedir\$modelname
}

# Move the rpt files to new dir created
Move-Item -Path $sourcedir\*.rpt -Destination $sourcedir\$modelname

# Using GetChildItem (i.e. Dir in dos) command with the pipe, will send a list of files to the Rename-Item command
# The Rename-Item command is replacing the modelname string with new modelname string defined at the start
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir\$modelname | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $modelname, $newmodelname }

# You can remove the stuff below this line -----
# Pause here so you can check the result.

# List renamed files in their new directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir\$modelname
# rem Pause
Write-Host "Press any key"
$pause = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# rem End ------
```

Comment: Hi Guys thank you for your efforts in answering the questions. I posted another link using only powershell which also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402209/renaming-and-moving-files-powershell