# Renaming and Moving Files Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to rename .rpt files from dr_network to dr_network_10yr. Then create the folder Output (if it does not exist) and move the files to the folder.

The renaming of the files works however cannot move the files. Note the files should be relative pathing.

Thank you for your assistance.

```powershell
New-Item .\Output -force
Get-ChildItem *.rpt | 
    ForEach-Object{
        Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace 'dr_network_','dr_network_10yr')
        Move-Item $_($_.Fullname -destination ".\Output")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your example does not work for several reasons. You need to specify a type on New-Item

```
New-Item .\Output -force -ItemType Directory
```

You then get all *.rpt files and iterate through them. The rename syntax is correct but you have issues with the move syntax. Powershell has no idea what you are trying to do. You are also renaming a file and then attempting to move a file that no longer exists as you have renamed it. The following should help:

```
#Tell powershell its a directory
New-Item .\Output -force -ItemType Directory
Get-ChildItem *.rpt | 
    ForEach-Object{
        #store the new name as a variable
        $newName = $_.FullName -replace 'dr_network_','dr_network_10yr'
        #rename the file
        Rename-Item $_ $newName
        #move the newly renamed file to the Output folder
        Move-Item $newName -destination ".\Output"
}
```

Comment: thank you the answer that helps. Firstly is the difference between the Get-ChildItem *.rpt and Get-Item .\*.rpt. I believe I can use both options in this case. Secondly, I should stated this in my question, I only want to move the items that get the renaming.

Comment: As it is this will get all *.RPT files, attempt to rename them, and attempt to move the renamed files. Any files that are not renamed will not be touched. To get a better understanding of what is going on, try to copy some sample files to a working directory, put the script i posted into the ISE, add breakpoints with F9 and attempt to step through the script. Add -whatif statements to the rename and move commands and see exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm following from your other post, which helps understand hat you are trying to do:

[cmd insert text into the middle of the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102579/cmd-insert-text-into-the-middle-of-the-file-name/28421118#28421118)

I have modified my code to do what you would like it to.  It only moves and renames rpt files with the "modelname" or "dr network" at the beginning.  You can change this of you like.

It also lets you specify the SourceDir, or you can leave the value as "." for relative pathing.

```
# Rename using replace to insert text in the middle of the name

# Set directory where the files you want to rename reside
# This will allow you to run the script from outside the source directory
Set-Variable -Name sourcedir -Value "."

# Set folder and rename variables
Set-Variable -Name modelname -Value "dr network_"
Set-Variable -Name id        -Value "10yr_"

# Set new filename which is modelname string + id variable
Set-Variable -Name newmodelname -Value $modelname$id

# Check if folder exisits, if not create
if(!(Test-Path -Path $sourcedir\$modelname )){
    # rem make directoy with modelname variable
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $sourcedir\$modelname
}

# Move the rpt files to new dir created
Move-Item -Path $sourcedir\$modelname*.rpt -Destination $sourcedir\$modelname

# Using GetChildItem (i.e. Dir in dos) command with the pipe, will send a list of files to the Rename-Item command
# The Rename-Item command is replacing the modelname string with new modelname string defined at the start
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir\$modelname | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $modelname, $newmodelname }

# You can remove the stuff below this line -----
# Pause here so you can check the result.

# List renamed files in their new directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir\$modelname
# rem Pause
Write-Host "Press any key"
$pause = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# rem End ------
```

Hope you get it working.

Comment: @StephenP the rpt files are simple txt files renamed with a rpt file extension. Any text editor can easily open it. So in must programming languages you can easily open, edit, delete and close the files. Nothing special with them. do you guys (or anyone else know the different between Get-Item and Get-ChildItem. I am guesing here however is the Get-ChildItem used for files and folders in the local directory and Get-Item is only related to files. Is this right?

Comment: @tfitzhardinge in brief:

Get-Item gets the item (file or directory) at the specified location. It **does not** get the contents of the item at the location. (unless you use a wildcard character (*) to request all the contents of the item.)

Get-Childitem gets the items and child items in one or more specified locations.

example:
Get-Item c:  (returns only c: directory)
Get-Item c:\*  (returns c: files and folders)
Get-ChildItem   (returns c: files and folders)

[link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)
[link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849788.aspx)